# How to change the value of a style attribute with class name 'image' in console?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i change the attribute value of a class in console on a browser.

Here i want to change the margin-top from 40px to 400px, is it even possible to change from console ?

```html
<div>
<img class="image" style="margin-top:40px;" src="#">
</div>
```

P.S - New to JS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the element in the element inspector. When you have done so, the element currently selected is available in the console as `$0` variable.

So if you have selected the image in the element inspector, you can do

```
$0.style.marginTop = '400px'
```

in the console.

If you want to replace the whole attribute value with your own string:

```
$0.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 400px');
```

If you have more than one of these elements on the page, and you want to change them in a loop:

```
for (const image of document.querySelectorAll('img.image')) {
  image.style.marginTop = '400px';
  // or
  // image.setAttribute('style', 'margin-top: 400px');
}
```

Comment: so if i want to change external css from console ?

Comment: Inline styles override external CSS, unless you need to overwrite a rule that is specified using `!important` (in which case your console assignment would also have to make use of that). You are aware that any console changes are lost as soon as the page reloads?

Comment: Yes i am aware of that, i didn't knew that i could change from console because i wanted to catch the particular attribute in a loop. 
Thanks

Comment: *i wanted to catch the particular attribute in a loop* this makes me think you need a solution in a script, not in the console (which you asked for explicitly), right?

Comment: Yup, now i will try creating a script first. If unsuccessful then will again post a question, hopefully you will be answering it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, if you assume that only one image exists with the `image` class:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].style.marginTop = '400px';
```

Comment: It sets directly the inline style attribute to your specified styled.

Comment: so if i want to change external css from console ?

Comment: If you mean by external already existed CSS, then yes it will be overwritten.

Comment: *if you assume that only one image exists with the image class* then you'd use `document.querySelector('.image')`

Answer (score 1):

you can use `setAttribute` to modify  your inline style

```
document.getElementsByClassName("image")[0].setAttribute("style", "margin-top: 400px");
```